# Getting multiple Distinct grouped values in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, distinct

Haven't been able to specifically find, answers to my question..

I need to get a result that display: Project name ONCE, with all the users that have made `timeEntries` on that project, in a given date range.

And I need to get the `timeEntries` (`hoursEntered`) as well, so I can calculate how many hours have been spent on that project in total..

I am new to this, so I hope i have provided enough information..

my code:

```
var dateStart = new DateTime (2016,09,01);
var dateEnd   = new DateTime (2016,09,19);

var query = (from timeEntry in TimeEntries
        join task in Tasks on timeEntry.TaskID equals task.TaskID
        join project in Projects on task.ProjectID equals project.ProjectID
        where timeEntry.DateEntity >= dateStart && timeEntry.DateEntity <= dateEnd
        select new {
        User = timeEntry.User.FirstName + " "+timeEntry.User.LastName,
        Project = timeEntry.Task.Project.ProjectName,
        ProjectId = timeEntry.Task.ProjectID,
        HoursEntered = timeEntry.HoursEntered
        }).GroupBy (q => q.Project).Distinct();
```

i have 4 tables :

- Projects (ProjectID, ProjectName)
- Tasks (TaskID, ProjectID)
- TimeEntries (HoursEntered, DateEntity, TaskID)
- Users (FirstName, LastName)

Comment: Add your `TimeEntries` class to your post, please.

Comment: my class ? TimeEntries is my table from DB.

Comment: He needs the property/columns, like `hoursEntered` etc

Comment: added the ones i use in () at each table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query =
  from timeEntry in TimeEntries
  where timeEntry.DateEntity >= dateStart && timeEntry.DateEntity <= dateEnd
  select new {
    User = timeEntry.User.FirstName + " "+timeEntry.User.LastName,
    Project = timeEntry.Task.Project.ProjectName,
    ProjectId = timeEntry.Task.ProjectID,
    HoursEntered = timeEntry.HoursEntered
  }

var localRows = query.ToList();

var groups = localRows.GroupBy(x => x.Project);

var projects = groups.Select(g => new {
  Project = g.Key,
  Hours = g.Sum(x => x.HoursEntered),
  Users = g.Select(x => x.User).Distinct().ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: this one is really close, but i still get multiple records of the same username.. i need it to display only on of each user that has entered hours into the project.

Comment: Fair enough, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with:

```
var query = (from timeEntry in TimeEntries
        join task in Tasks on timeEntry.TaskID equals task.TaskID
        join project in Projects on task.ProjectID equals project.ProjectID
        where timeEntry.DateEntity >= dateStart && timeEntry.DateEntity <= dateEnd
        group timeEntry by new { proyect.ProjectID, proyect.ProjectName } into g
        select new {
        TimeEntries = g.ToArray(),
        Project = g.Key.ProjectName ,
        ProjectId = g.Key.ProjectID,
        HoursEntered = g.Sum(e => e.HoursEntered)
        });
```

I need more info to adjust it more, but I think this should help you. I did it on the browse, so mybe you need to check names.

[Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Comment: Pretty good, have a +1.  Also, be careful using this on a database.  LinqToSql is likely to do extra queries to fetch the TimeEntries = g.ToArray part.

Comment: this one gets way too much data that i don't need. and doesn't give me the usernames

Comment: Well, as you are the only one who knows the data base and what you need, just adjust the query. 

+1 to the LinqToSql. But YAGNI except for a big Database.